# Move files that have the same case-insensitive filename

Tags: shell-script, files, filenames, ftp, case-sensitivity

I have been asked by the data owner to copy a specific folder (and its large amount of subfolders and files) via FTPS to our cloud storage provider. I am using LFTP for that, and the upload worked well until I hit a snag.

There are several folders with multiple files that have the same filename except for case. For example, folder *data* has the following files: 
*testfile1.txt*, *TestFile1.TXT*

When I try to upload those via LFTP, I get an error that the file already exists. So for my purposes, I need the files to be case-insensitive before uploading. To address this issue, I would like to use a script that searches the current directory recursively, and moves any case-insensitive duplicates to a subfolder. In my example above, I would want the script to create a subfolder called *Duplicates* and then move *TestFile1.TXT* into it. I suppose it's possible that I could have multiple duplicated filenames, so the script should create a *Duplicates2* folder for the second duplicated filename, and so on.

Also, I should note that for the few "duplicated" files that I checked, they had differing filesizes. I am not going to make any assumptions about the files being **actual** duplicates, which is why I want to move them rather than delete them.

Comment: What is the filesystem you're copying _to_?  Most native POSIX filesystems are entirely case-sensitive, so `testfile1.txt` and `TestFile1.txt` are in fact two different, nonconflicting filenames.

Comment: I just tested the cloud storage platform's case-sensitivity by uploading a file, changing the filename case, then uploading the original file again. It overwrote the renamed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash script below loops through the files in the current directory, looking for duplicate filenames case insensitively. If a match is found, it looks to create a "Duplicates" folder that doesn't exist already, then moves the duplicate file into that directory.

The outer loop is there in order to re-compute the file globs (`*`) for the loops, in case a file gets moved. The outer loop runs until no files are moved.

```
#!/bin/bash

changes=1
while [ $changes -gt 0 ]
do
  changes=0
  for one in *
  do
    for two in *
    do
      shopt -u nocasematch
      # if it's the exact same filename, skip
      [[ "$one" == "$two" ]] && continue
      shopt -s nocasematch
      # if the file name matches case-insensitively, then mv it
      if [[ "$one" == "$two" ]]
      then
        suffix=
        while [ -d Duplicates"${suffix}" ]
        do
          suffix=$((suffix + 1))
        done
        mkdir Duplicates"${suffix}"
        mv "$two" Duplicates"${suffix}"
        changes=1
        break
      fi
    done
  done
done
```

With these sample files:

```
afile.txt
TestFile1.TXT
TESTfile1.txT
testfile1.txt
```

A sample run of the script creates:

```
$ tree .
.
├── afile.txt
├── Duplicates
│   └── TestFile1.TXT
├── Duplicates1
│   └── testfile1.txt
└── TESTfile1.txT
```

Comment: Thank you for the script! Unfortunately I'm getting a syntax error, and being a Linux noob, I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you run it with bash, @Joe? What's the error you get?

Comment: I created a .sh file with the code, and here's what I got: 

[username@text test]$ MvDuplicates.sh
/home/username/scripts/MvDuplicates.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected toke' `do
'home/username/scripts/MvDuplicates.sh: line 6: `  do

Comment: I then explicitly ran it with bash to be sure: "bash -x MvDuplicates.sh"

Comment: [username@text test]$ bash -x MvDuplicates.sh
+ LMOD_PKG=/usr/share/lmod/lmod
+ LMOD_DIR=/usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec
+ LMOD_CMD=/usr/share/lmod/lmod/libexec/lmod
+ MODULESHOME=/usr/share/lmod/lmod
+ export LMOD_PKG
+ export LMOD_CMD
+ export LMOD_DIR
+ export MODULESHOME
+ '[' -z -XqeMRF ']'
+ '[' -z more ']'
+ LMOD_VERSION=6.0.15
+ export LMOD_VERSION
+ '[' : '!=' : ']'
+ unalias ml
+ true
++ echo YES
++ tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
+ export_module=yes
+ '[' -n '4.1.2(1)-release' -a yes '!=' no ']'
+ export -f module
+ export -f ml

Comment: + unset export_module
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' 4 -ge 3 ']'
+ '[' -r /usr/share/lmod/lmod/init/lmod_bash_completions ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ changes=$'1\r'
/home/username/scripts/MvDuplicates.sh: MvDuplicates.sh: line 6: syntax error nea' unexpected token `do
'home/username/scripts/MvDuplicates.sh: MvDuplicates.sh: line 6: `  do

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I coulnd't figure out the forum syntax.

Comment: The `\r` in there makes me wonder if the script was edited in a DOS/WINDOWS mode, leaving carriage returns in the file. Try creating the file with a different editor, with a native Unix editor, or in a different editor save mode.

Comment: That's probably it, thanks. I'm terrible with VIM so I'll try something on Mac maybe.

Comment: Even something like `cat > scriptfile` (Enter) (paste script) then hit control-d; would create the file in a simple way.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, and the script works well. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Happy to hear! You should be able to click the check mark to tell future viewers that this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a very complex script to sort out case sensitive you can actually make the FTP case sensitive so you don't need to do this. Refer the LFTP [man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.pdf) for specifics on options: Check  if your LFTP command actually is has no case flag in it.

> -i, --nocase               case-insensitive pattern matching

You can transfer the folders as is file names should valid on the host. Adding more details about destination host would help.

Also I'd recommend to check if you can implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921818/lftp-mget-ignoring-case) base on file extension.

> LFTP mget ignoring case
>
> ***.[cC][sS][vV]**

I'm sure you don't have that issue as well.

If still the actual requirement is to have a script. You can create a python script using set.

Comment: Thank you, but this won't help since my FTP destination filesystem is not case sensitive.